# When should I use #ifdef instead of if()?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

When working in Objective-C, when is it appropriate to use preprocessor directives like
`#ifdef`, `#if`, `#ifndef`, and `#define` instead of statements like `if()` and `switch()`?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking the difference between compile-time and run-time "branching"?

Comment: euh, those two things are entirely different, so I guess you should go read a book on objective c first!

Comment: There are no pros and cons of using one or the other. "as opposed to ..." makes no sense because they are not related in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor directives like `#ifdef`, etc. are only valid at compile time. They are not able to make decisions or loops at runtime. They simply regulate what gets compiled and what not.

They are totally useless at runtime. They serve a totally different purpose.

Comment: what purpose are they generally used for?

Comment: Ive been playing around with them I now get what you mean. thanks for  clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 2):

These are all part of the C language, there's nothing specific to Objective-C here.

Most of the time in your program logic you're going to be using switches, if-elses, fors, whiles, etc. This applies to C, C++, Objective-C and other C-style languages.

Preprocessor directives are evaluated at compile-time, and so only the preprocessor/compiler is interested in that logic. Your actual program doesn't deal with any of this. You're not going to use directives much except for stuff like architecture differences, compile-time constants, macros and so on.